# fwrite in C, it doesn't write the correct word in file

Tags: c

I think this is a simple question but I can't get around to find the answer.

I want to write an array into a file. **text** is the array and **number** is the number of words in the array.

It runs but in the *newfile.txt* I don't get the text I want. It prints chinese characters, a lot of spaces. In shorts it's a mess. The problem, I think, is what I store in the memory but I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Thank you in advance! :)

```
void makefile(char **text,int number) {
    FILE * mf;
    mf = fopen("newfile.txt", "wt");
    fwrite(text,sizeof(text),number,mf);
    fclose(mf);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(text)` will give you the size of an *address*; I think you want the size of a `char`.  Also, I'd guess the compiler complained about passing a `char**` to `fwrite`; you should listen to it.

Comment: I'm guessing you think `char **text` refers to a 2-dimensional array.  It doesn't.  `text` is a ***pointer*** to an array of `char *` pointers.  Each of those `char *` pointers in the array that `text` points to are likely pointers to completely separate one-dimensional arrays of `char` values.  `char **text` is not the same as `char text[][]` even though they are dereferenced with the same syntax.

Comment: Okay, I understand it, but I have to use fwrite(), is there any possible way I can make it work, maybe change it or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `char **text` is a pointer to an array of pointers, each of them pointing to a line of text to be printed. So you will need a loop to iterate over these pointers and write each of them separately. Otherwise, you write a number of addresses in binary format rather than any text, and that's the mess you observe in the file then.

The loop could look as follows:

```
for (int i=0;i<number;i++) {
   fputs(text[i], mf);
}
```

If, for some reason, you need to use `fwrite`, you would write:

```
for (int i=0;i<number;i++) {
   fwrite(text[i],1,strlen(text[i]),mf);
}
```

Comment: It is important to use fwrite(). Is there any way I can do it?